# libGDX - orthographic camera and world units

Tags: java, libgdx, camera, projection-matrix

I've followed the advice in [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70361/libgdx-android-phone-resolution-problem) to handle world/screen coordinates, but I'm getting results I don't quite understand, as I'm not terribly good in math.

So, when I use this code:

```
SpriteBatch batch;
OrthographicCamera camera;
public static float width = 0, height = 0;

private void setupGraphics(SpriteBatch batch) {
    height = Constants.TILES_Y; // 20
    float pixelsPerUnit = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / height;
    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / pixelsPerUnit;
    Gdx.app.log("debug", "Width: " + width + " height: " + height + " ppu: " + pixelsPerUnit);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    camera.position.set(0, 0 / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
}
```

...the result looks like this - it seems that the view height is now 20 pixels, not 20 32x32 tiles:

[image: buggy scene]

However, when I add a multiplier to the height, like 16, the result looks like this, which is more like what I want:

[image: correct scene]

Here's the changed code:

```
    height = Constants.TILES_Y * Constants.TILES_MULTIPLIER; // 20 * 16
```

How would I modify the code to avoid having to supply the multiplier every time when I handle coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MrIlliteracy for the extensive answer. I finally managed to wrap my head around this, I got it to work by setting the target width and height to 1 unit in my rendering method, like this:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, Point location) {
    if(tileset != null) {
        batch.draw(
                tileset, // a libGDX Texture
                location.getX(), 
                location.getY(), 
                1, 1, // ADDED THESE
                (int)bottomLeft.getX() * Constants.TILE_DIM, 
                (int)bottomLeft.getY() * Constants.TILE_DIM, Constants.TILE_DIM, 
                Constants.TILE_DIM, 
                false, false // flips to get the right method overload
        );
    }
}
```

The program now looks like this:

[image: game rendered correctly]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend re-reading the post as I don't think you completely understand why you're setting up an orthographic camera.

The whole point of this is to move *away* from pixels and move towards your own unit that doesn't depend on screen size. This way, everything can be properly scaled no matter the device.

`it seems that the view height is now 20 pixels, not 20 32x32 tiles:` - It's not 20 pixels, it's 20 units high. As I said above, these units are basically your new pixels that scale with the device's screen.

To answer your question, `How would I modify the code to avoid having to supply the multiplier every time when I handle coordinates?`, the answer is: you don't.

There are other things you can do though like have your tile rendering method take in a coordinate in "tiles coordinates" and then it multiplies by the tile size when you draw it.

Here's a little diagram I drew up quickly to explain it graphically.
[image: Infographic]